# WCF Deploy Strange Contract behavior

Tags: wcf

WCF service deployed to IIS7 server sitting on WinServer2008 Standard SP2.

DataContract int Members are being 'lost'

i.e. All ints sent by the client emerge as 0 into the Contract processing logic on the Server

I made a 'Reflection' contract (Take incoming int turn it to string and return it). When the test harness is pointed at the WCF Contract running in the IDE the ints are reflected OK. When it is pointed at the Deployed contract zeros are reflected.

Deployment:
Made an IIS Application on the Server and did a file deployment to the physical directory.

The Deployed Service appears OK. i.e. The 'real' client app (VS2008 WinMobile 6.5  app under development separate solution) has a WebService reference that sees the Deployed WCF OK . It is just that the variable values generated by the client get lost on the wire. Only happens to Client generated variables. The client is able to consume Server generated DataContract Variables with the expected values. It is something to do with base types. The first victim was client generated dates so I moved these into strings for the journey. 
Web.config is below.
thanks
Bob

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
   <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove     the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the web Application from Production server and remade it. Problem partially solved. Test windows app now sees the ints reflected. However the WinMobile client still doesn't. Tested using string values for the contract and it works. Life is too short for this. I shall alter the Contracts to strings strings strings. So much for strongly typed Data Contracts.